# Function to count words, from not where expected

Tags: oracle

I am trying to do a function that count words in a string ignoring spaces, dots, comas, etc... so I started with just ignoring simple spaces, so far this works

```
Select length ('Hello World') - length(REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello World',
'( ){1,}', '')) into NumDePalabras + 1
from dual;
```

But when trying to make it into a function that gets as parameter a String and return the number or words it isn't working right now the error is FROM keyword not found where expected.

any ideas of how can I get this to work?

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE Function WCount
       ( txt IN varchar2 )
        RETURN varchar2
    IS
        resul varchar2(100);

    BEGIN


    Select length (txt) - length(REGEXP_REPLACE(txt,
    '( ){1,}', '')) NumDePalabras + 1 from dual;

    RETURN resul;

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       raise_application_error(-20001,'se ha encontrado un error - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
    END;
```

Comment: Skip the query and use `resul := length(txt)...` or even  `return length(txt)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL>     create or replace function countword(txt varchar2) return varchar2 is
  2      resul varchar2(100);
  3      BEGIN
  4
  5      Select (length (txt) - length(REGEXP_REPLACE(txt,'( ){1,}', '')) ) into resul from dual;
  6
  7      RETURN resul+1;
  8
  9      EXCEPTION
 10      WHEN OTHERS THEN
 11         raise_application_error(-20001,'se ha encontrado un error - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
 12      END;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Very close to what I ended doing as well, and this works elegantly. Thanks

Comment: Such an exception block is itself a bug. It will never show the exact line number where the error occurs.